# How do I get the TOTAL NUMBER of FRAME of a Video file?

Tags: c#, multimedia

How do I get the TOTAL NUMBER OF FRAME of a Video file? I'm developing Video Velocity Meter Software
That compute the average velocity of a moving object in a video but the problem is I can't figure out how to get the TotalNumberOfFrame of specific video.

Formula:

```
Total time= ObjectFrameRate (f/s) * (1/ TotalNumberOfFrame)
```

AveVelocity=Displacement/TotalTime

Comment: what do you call a "total frame rate"? The frame rate I get it, the total number of frames also, but "total frame rate"???

Comment: This will be totally different throughout the different video file and codec types. You need to get more specific on the type of video you are using.

Comment: That's what I mean total number of frame?

Comment: Do you mean the total number of frames?

Comment: YeS that's what I mean

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the "Dexter 1.0 TypeLib". You need to add a reference to it first. It's found under the COM objects (the lib is by MS). Then you could use this code:

```
string filePath = "C:\\testVideo.avi";
MediaDet md = new MediaDetClass(); 
md.Filename = filePath; 
md.CurrentStream = 0;
double FrameRate = md.FrameRate;
```

Comment: It return the total number of frame?

Comment: I'm getting the error 'DexterLib.MediaDetClass' has no constructors define

Comment: That is strange as it is working perfectly for me. But you will have to multiply the framerate with the videos duration in seconds.